# VBA Run Time error in Excel 2013 that works well in Excel 2010

Tags: excel-2010, excel-2013

I have a macro that we were using for years and worked well in Excel 2010. However, now that we upgraded to Excel 2013, it gives a run time error 9.
The following code part is highlighted after debugging it:

```
Sheets(1).Copy after:=Workbooks(mfname).Sheets(3)
```

I know already that this error has to do something with the availability of the range. The question is if there is any easy fix to this? The relevant code-snippet:

```
Workbooks.Add
mfname= ActiveWorkbook.Name

Workbooks.Open template
template_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Sheets(1).Copy after:=Workbooks(mfname).Sheets(3)

Workbooks(mfname).Activate
Sheets(1).Delete
Sheets(1).Delete
Sheets(1).Delete
lapok = Sheets.Count
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert in VBA, but little google searching says error 9 is subscript out of range error.

This likely is from `Sheets(3)`. I also remember excel had 3 sheets open by default in those versions. Maybe that is not the case now, and causing the problem.

Comment: Hi, yes - This was the issue, I amended the code a bit and added the two missing sheets to the target workbook and now it is working again!
THank you for the help!